# stocks weekly OHLC

Tags: sas

I have stock data and want to find very stock weekly open, high, low and close. Thanks in advance.

Sample data..

```
name        date        open    high    low    close
20MICRONS   11/07/2012  86.65   98.20   85.05   94.50
20MICRONS   12/07/2012  94.60   96.80   92.00   92.35
20MICRONS   02/11/2012  125.55  149.80  125.50  148.05
20MICRONS   07/11/2012  161.90  167.00  148.15  151.05
A2ZMES      02/07/2012  109.25  114.90  108.00  113.80
A2ZMES      03/07/2012  115.00  115.95  112.05  112.85
A2ZMES      24/09/2012  66.95   70.80   64.00   70.05
A2ZMES      25/09/2012  70.35   72.50   70.15   70.85
AANJANEYA   03/07/2012  485.15  494.80  478.65  486.50
AANJANEYA   04/07/2012  489.05  491.10  482.55  486.70
AARTIDRUGS  05/11/2012  198.35  199.00  188.00  190.50
AARTIDRUGS  06/11/2012  192.00  192.95  186.95  191.55
AARTIIND    14/09/2012  79.90   81.65   78.65   78.95
AARTIIND    17/09/2012  78.30   79.25   78.00   78.55
AARTIIND    06/12/2012  100.70  100.90  99.00   99.70
AARTIIND    07/12/2012  100.00  100.00  96.00   96.60
```

Comment: This question does not have any statistical content, so it is better suited to stackoverflow. But still you need to improve it, since in its current state it is hard to understand what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the actual question is:  you cannot simulate `FIRST.var` and `LAST.var` processing in `PROC SQL`.  These automatic variables are created by SAS during sequential data step processing.

It's not entirely clear what the second paragraph is about.